# Automatically generate pages for Mysql table rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on creating a PHP/mysql quiz application. I outlined my table structure here:
[MySql database design for a quiz program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103321/mysql-database-design-for-a-quiz-program)

Now I am looking for a way to automatically generate the actual quiz pages. Once I enter the corresponding data in the "quizzes" table, I want a page to be automatically created containing all the corresponding questions/answers with the same quiz ID. A link to this quiz would then be added to a list of all the quizzes somewhere.

Basically, I want everything to be automated once the data is entered in the mySQL tables.

All I can really think is that once each page is created for the quiz, I could use a while or for loop that identifies all the questions with the same ID as the quiz, and create those. Then another nested while/for loop that generates the matching answers for each question. As for creating actual each quiz page, I am a bit lost.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single page (i.e. `quiz.php`) and use GET variables to fetch the data you need.

Don't generate the pages beforehand, it's usually over-complicated and redundant.

Comment: If I do it this way, is there any way to still maintain a list of all the quizzes and clicking each one just goes to quiz.php (and then the correct id)?

Comment: @Jakemmarsh: Aye, `quiz.php?id={quiz_id_here}`